# CCmake installation changes my cmake version back to 2.8

Tags: cmake

I've installed latest Cmake version (3.2.2) in Ubuntu 14.04LTS
after i install `ccmake` through

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
```

It runs as cmake 2.8.12

But I need Cmake 3x versions to be executed

Comment: How did you install cmake 3.2.2? I don't think ccmake is just a generic frontend, each version of cmake should provide its own ccmake: if you build from source then the cmake-3.2.x/bin should contain a ccmake binary as well as a cmake binary.

Comment: I built it through source file downloaded from cmake.org

Comment: Three options: build ccmake from sources too, find a PPA with cmake/ccmake for trusty, update to vivid and install cmake/ccmake from debian-stretch repository.